# Can not make use of parameter nb10 in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, variables, parameters, limit

Is there a limit to the number of parameters I can pass into a bash script? It seems that nb 9 works fine byt nb10 is disregarded.

I tried using audio = {10}

because I read it somewhere but that doesn't seem to work either...

Call (from a local php file):

```
exec('nohup sudo -u brftv /home/brftv/sizetest.sh ft7gy8hu9ji0.mp4 800 600 94 64 305 660 1 h23 1> /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

The bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/sync
#width=`/bin/cat size|/bin/sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\x\([0-9]*\)/\1/'`
#height=`/bin/cat size|/bin/sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\x\([0-9]*\)/\2/'`
width=1920
height=1080
gwidth=$6
gheight=$7
nwidth=$2
nheight=$3
oposx=$4
oposy=$5
nwidth=$gwidth
fsfile="/usr/share/nginx/www/cloudsign_local/video/keepFullscreen"
#echo $*>/home/brftv/testkommando

nheight=`eval expr $nwidth \\\* $height / $width`
if [ $nheight -gt $gheight ]
  then
    nheight=$gheight
    nwidth=`eval expr $nheight \\\* $width / $height`
fi
posy=`eval expr $oposy + $gheight / 2 - $nheight / 2`
posx=`eval expr $oposx + $gwidth / 2 - $nwidth / 2`

fullscreen=$8
vcodec=$9
audio=${10}

echo audio>/home/brftv/tiovar
#prints an empty file!!! a bool is passed, should always be 0 or 1...

case $audio in
  1)
defflags="-display :0 -x $nwidth -y $nheight -vo vdpau -ao alsa:device=hw=1.7 -nograbpointer -geometry $posx:$posy -nolirc -nortc -noconsolecontrols -nojoystick -slave -noborder -ontop"
;;
  0)
defflags="-display :0 -x $nwidth -y $nheight -vo vdpau -nosound -nograbpointer -geometry $posx:$posy -nolirc -nortc -noconsolecontrols -nojoystick -slave -noborder -ontop"
;;
esac

#ARK active audio -ao alsa:device=hw=1.7
#defflags="-display :0 -x $nwidth -y $nheight -vo vdpau -geometry $posx:$posy -really-quiet -nolirc -nojoystick -slave -noborder -ontop -ss 130"

vcodec=`echo $vcodec | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
case $vcodec in
ffh264|ffwmv3|ffmpeg12|ffvc1)
vcodec=${vcodec}vdpau
mplflags="$defflags -vc $vcodec"
;;
h264|H264|vc1|VC1|wmv3|WMV3|mpeg12|MPEG12)
vcodec=ff${vcodec}vdpau
mplflags="$defflags -vc $vcodec"
;;
*)
mplflags="$defflags"
;;
esac

case $fullscreen in
  1)
    DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xdotool key Ctrl+F2
    /usr/bin/mplayer $mplflags -fs $1
    echo "/usr/bin/mplayer $mplflags -fs $1">/tmp/mplayer
    if [ -f "$fsfile" ]; then
    echo "fullscreen file not found"
    else
    #DEBUG /usr/bin/mplayer $mplflags -fs /home/brftv/videos/cosmopolis_trlr_01_1080p_dl.mov
    DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xdotool key Ctrl+F1
    fi
;;
  0)
    /usr/bin/mplayer $mplflags $1
    echo "mplayer $mplflags $1"
;;
esac
```

Note: Worked nice before I added that 10th parameter...

Comment: `eval` is unnecessary for math. Either use `nheight=$( expr $nwidth \* $height / $width)`; or much, much better, `nheight=$(( $nwidth * $height / $width))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`audio=${10}` is correct. As the `bash` manual says:

> When a positional parameter consisting of more than a single digit is expanded, it must be enclosed  in  braces  (see  EXPANSION below).

The error is the line after that:

```
echo audio>/home/brftv/tiovar
```

It should be:

```
echo "$audio" > /home/brftv/tiovar
```

You forgot the `$`.

I'm not sure why you're getting an empty file, you should be getting a file with the word "audio" in it.

BTW, you should use `escapeshellarg` when putting URL parameters into a command line, otherwise you're opening yourself up to some serious injection problems.

Comment: Hm there must be something else wrong then. Because if I hard set the fullscreen to TRUE and instead use that flag (bool as well) for the audio, everything works fine. Value of audio is printed to the file tiovar and script runs as it should.

Comment: OK fixed it. Apparently there must be a space between the last parameter and that >

Comment: No, there's no need for a space before `>`. It must be something else.